# I need help pinpointing why my React Materials UI mobile version of AppBar will not render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to create an `AppBar` Component that opens a `Drawer` component when the screen size of my website reaches a certain amount of pixels. For reference, the functionality that I am trying to mimic is the one found on [React UI's](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer) Drawer component. When I try to implement the `AppBar` and `Drawer` components together and render the page, I receive this error and a maximum stack size call error.

```
warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing
state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). 
Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects 
are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

As the warning error states, I have tried moving my code into the the `componentWillMount` stage of React. Here is the code:

```
 43 class MobileAppBar extends Component {
 44   constructor(props) {
 45     super(props);
 46   }
 47
 48   componentWillMount() {
 49     this.state = {open: false}
 50   }
 51
 52   handleToggle(e) {
 53     this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
 54   }
 55
 56   render() {
 57     return(
 58       <AppBar title="Daniel Rubio" onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle()}>
 59         <Drawer open={this.state.open}>
 60           <MenuItem> Menu Item </MenuItem>
 61           <MenuItem> Menu Item </MenuItem>
 62         </Drawer>
 63       </AppBar>
 64     );
 65   }
 66 }
```

I have read the documentation of the React's life cycle and have tried to place my code in `ComponentDidMount` and the error still persists. Additonally, I am simply trying to follow this blog tutorial but still cannot get this to work. The link can be found here[AppBar Menu Tutorial](https://medium.com/@sanfordb/using-material-ui-s-app-bar-with-left-nav-in-react-d9311a49b3d0#.j8m13vlfa). Could someone please assist me. I've been working on this for hours and would love to finally get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these errors happen when you `setState` inside `render()` (which then calls another render, and so on). When using brackets (`()`) to call functions in React, they are called every render, not when a certain event happens. So try and change this:

```
onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle()}
```

to this:

```
onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
```

Example showing this behaviour:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    console.log('Called but not clicked!');
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div onClick={this.onClick()}>Hello World</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```